# Anyone tried to compile Intel xf86_video_intel for another OS

Tags: linux, video, intel

Has anyone tried to compile Intel xf86_video_intel for another OS.  This code is written for Linux.  I am wondering if there is any experience with porting the code to another operating system?  The code is located at:

http://intellinuxgraphics.org/documentation.html

Thanks,
FM

Comment: What operating system are you talking about? It might work on a unix-like OS that support X.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Intel Linux graphics drivers are very dependent of features of the linux kernel (kernel mode setting being one of the most talked about recently). Porting the driver may not be a trivial, if possible, task.

Answer (score -1):

Usually Linux graphic code is written for the X server. X is available for many different platforms / OS'es. For more information see (http://www.x.org/wiki/).